# Error C2246: cannot access private member

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2010

I'm stumped on this compiler error, and I can't figure out for the life of me what is going on. The whole error doesn't make a whole lot of sense to me, and what makes it stranger that most of this code is copied from a former project where it worked fine.

The error and the code follow:

```
1>ClCompile:
1>  main.cpp
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\fstream(1347): error C2248: 'std::basic_ios<_Elem,_Traits>::basic_ios' : cannot access private member declared in class 'std::basic_ios<_Elem,_Traits>'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ios(176) : see declaration of 'std::basic_ios<_Elem,_Traits>::basic_ios'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          This diagnostic occurred in the compiler generated function 'std::basic_fstream<_Elem,_Traits>::basic_fstream(const std::basic_fstream<_Elem,_Traits> &)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>
1>Build FAILED.
```

And here is the very minor code of *main.cpp**:

```
#include <Mage/File/PlainText.h>
#include <cstdio>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    Mage::FilePlainText file = Mage::FilePlainText("shadow_pcf_gaussian_fragment.glsl");
    printf("%s\n", file.content().c_str());

    while (true) { }

    return 0;
}
```

And the code **file.content():**

```
Mage::String FilePlainText::content() {
    Mage::String src;

    try {
        open();

        // We allocate enough memory to copy the entire content to memory.
        mHandle.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
        src.reserve(mHandle.tellg());

        // Set pointer to 0 and copy to memory.
        mHandle.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
        src.assign((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(mHandle)), 
                    std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());

        close();
    } catch (Mage::Exception& e) {
        throw e;
    }

    return src;
}
```

My guess is that it has something to do with this.

Comment: Do you have an argument or return type of `std::fstream` or a member variable of same type with default copy constructor for containing class anywhere? The error message is stating that an attempt is being to copy a stream, which is forbidden.

Comment: No, but std::fstream is a member of Mage::FilePlainText.

Comment: How is it initialized and is `FilePainText` copyable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll guess `FilePlainText` is (directly or indirectly) derived from `fstream`, or has a member of type `fstream` (in which case the copy constructor will attempt a copy) which isn't copyable, so

```
Mage::FilePlainText file = Mage::FilePlainText("shadow_pcf_gaussian_fragment.glsl");
```

is illegal. Why not simply:

```
Mage::FilePlainText file("shadow_pcf_gaussian_fragment.glsl");
```

I doubt you really want copy initialization.

Edit - you should probably make the copy constructor of `FilePlainText` `private` to prevent attempts at copying it.

Comment: No, but it does have a member that is std::fstream, which is a file handle. Your suggestion worked, thank you. I knew I was missing something obvious. (I'll accept it when the darn thing lets me!)

Comment: Also, could you perhaps tell me why it is that you can't copy std::fstream? This is intriguing.

Comment: @JesseBrands the member issue was also addressed in the answer.

Comment: @JesseBrands see this thread - http://compgroups.net/comp.lang.c++.moderated/std-ios_base-copy-constructor/471707

Comment: @JesseBrands re: "member that is std::fstream, which is a file handle" -- no, it's an object of type `std::fstream`. A file handle is a completely different beast; it's type is `FILE*`.

Comment: In C++11 an fstream will probably be movable which means you will also be able to move your object. This gets around issues where you don't actually want more copies but want to be able to return one from a function without having to use shared_ptr

Comment: Thank you, that clarified it. I accepted the answer now, too.